# PHP: How to extract() values from an associative array with hyphens/dashes in their keys?

Tags: php, wordpress, extract, hyphenation

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854742/using-extract-with-hyphens). Is it possible to `extract()` values from an associative array with hyphens/dashes in their keys **by now**?

It's about an older version of the [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Example:

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo-bar' => 'something'
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = ${foo-bar}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Comment: *`smacks forehead`* PHP still hasn't changed the rules on variable naming. If you need the values and you don't need them in variables you can use some other array parsing method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It is still not possible](https://3v4l.org/cnMmo). However, for the PHP.net engine, I have [an RFC under discussion](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/on_demand_name_mangling) that would make it possible in PHP 8.

Answer (score 4):

[shortcode_atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) returns an array so just use it.

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $params = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo-bar' => 'something'
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = " . $params['foo-bar'];
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Comment: Good answer but it lacks a precise answer to the problem with exporting the field.